# VBA Access Return Values When Calling a Function In Another Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to call a function in a module in Database B from a form in Database A.

I realize that in VBA, you can get a return value for a function by specifying a return type and using 'Set' to set a variable (which the same name as the function), which returns the value.

I have tried to call a function in Database B, using both db.Execute (which should return a Variant) and  by connecting to Database B and doing rst.Open (to return a recordset.)

Neither approach seems to return a value to the form in Database A.

Does anyone have sample code demonstrating this?

Comment: I am pretty sure db.Execute does not return anything. Ever. What does the function do? If it's a query, a recordset should do the trick.

Comment: When Database A is open in Access, it can't directly use a function defined in Database B unless you set a reference to Database B.

Comment: Hi, Post your current code demonstrating the two methods you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a recordset from a table that is not in the current database then you need to set the ADODB.Connection variable to the path of the new database. An example of that is:

```
Public Sub rdstALTDB()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim fPath as String
    Dim rsTest As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    fPath = C:/Test/TestDb.accdb 'location of the alternate database
    conn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " & fPath

    Set rsTest = New ADODB.Recordset

    rsTest.Open "Test", conn

    'Do Something With the recordset

     rsTest.Close
     Set rsTest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.